# VBA and late binding: Where do I find the numeric equivalents to constants?

Tags: vba, binding

I'm a complete VBA newbie, having decided to teach myself over a weekend, so forgive the stupid question(s).  I'm trying to automate some routine tasks involving generating Word documents or emails from an Excel Spreadsheet.  Because there will be multiple software versions involved, I am using late binding to open Word and Outlook.  My question is:  Where can I find a simple reference telling me what the index numbers are that correspond to the application constants?  I have killed a lot of time googling to learn that, for example, the Outlook foldertype for "Contacts" is "10".  Maybe someone knows of a web link that could save me countless hours of searching?

Update:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278936%28v=office.14%29.aspx seems to have some of the information I need, although it's not always intuitive where the information is. For example, if it contains the outlook folder type constants, I haven't found them yet.

Comment: In VB6 or any VBA editor press F2 (or View menu) for Object Browser. You'll need to right click and choose Add Reference. If you Add Reference to the Project the constants will be available no matter how you are binding. You don't have to use the objects early binding to use the constants.

Answer (score 0):

See here

Enumeration http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860961(v=office.15).aspx

OlDefaultFolders Enumeration http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861868(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add the relevant object libraries to your project as References during development time. You do this by using the *Tools* - *References* Menu in the VBA Editor. This makes developing a lot easier as you can use intellisense while writing the code.

If you need only a few Enums or single Constants in your code the easiest way to get their values is to hit `[F2]` in in VBA Editor while the object libraries are still referenced. Then search for the constants name and copy its value to your code.

Just using the numeric values of the constants in your code makes the code pretty hard to read. So I would recommend to re-declare all the Enums/Constants you actually use in a module in your own project. That massively improves the readability of your code.

So, instead of just copying the value from the VBA Object Browser, I suggest you copy the name and the value and put it your own code as a constant declaration. For your example of the Outlook contacts folder this will look like this:

```
Public Const olFolderContacts = 10
```

You can then use the constant in your procedures as you would do with Early Binding.

Should you work on a larger automation project using many of the constants from any one of the Office Object Libraries, you can download ready-made [VBA modules containing **all** the Office constants](http://codekabinett.com/page.php?Theme=10&Lang=2#office-automation-constants-vba-module) from my website. You can then just import the relevant modules into your project and are ready to go.

After you finished the main development work, you remove the linked libraries from your project and declare the relevant object variables `As Object` instead of the actual type.

Always remember to compile your project not to miss any declaration that does not work late binding.